# MySQL: Relate 5 tables LEFT JOIN and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, left-join

I have 5 tables:

- Table `usuarios`:

  ```
  | id_usuario | nombre_usuario  |
  | ---------- | --------------- |
  | 1          | jose perez      |
  | 2          | manolo garcia   |
  | 3          | antonio sanchez |
  ```
- Table `productos`:

  ```
  | id_producto | nombre_producto   |
  | ----------- | ----------------- |
  | 1           | camiseta espinete |
  | 2           | camiseta batman   |
  | 3           | camiseta simpson  |
  ```
- Table `favoritos`:

  ```
  | id_favoritos | id_producto | id_usuario |
  | ------------ | ----------- | ---------- |
  | 1            | 3           | 2          |
  | 2            | 1           | 3          |
  | 3            | 2           | 1          |
  ```
- Table `chistes`:

  ```
  | id_chiste | titulo_chiste    |
  | --------- | ---------------- |
  | 1         | chiste arevalo   |
  | 2         | chiste jose mota |
  | 3         | chiste gatos     |
  ```
- Table `likes`:

  ```
  | id_like | id_chiste | id_usuario |
  | ------- | --------- | ----  ---- |
  | 1       | 3         | 2          |
  | 2       | 1         | 3          |
  | 3       | 2         | 1          |
  ```

Where a `usuario` can add `productos` as `favoritos` and `likes` `chistes`. I am interested in knowing the total number of `favoritos` and `likes` of each `usuario` in the same query and ordering the list of `usuarios` by one or another amount (number of `favoritos` or number of `likes`, depending on what is selected). I know how to do it separately, that is, in two different queries:

- To list the `usuarios` with the total number of `favoritos` I use:

```
SELECT usuarios.*,
count(favoritos.id_usuario) AS numFavoritos
FROM usuarios
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON usuarios.id_usuario = favoritos.id_usuario
GROUP BY usuarios.id_usuario
ORDER BY numFavoritos DESC
```

- And to list the users with the total number of likes I use:

```
SELECT usuarios.*,
count(likes.id_usuario) AS numLikes
FROM usuarios
LEFT JOIN likes 
ON usuarios.id_usuario = likes.id_usuario
GROUP BY usuarios.id_usuario
ORDER BY numLikes DESC
```

I've been trying to do it in a single database query, but I can't.
If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it, greetings to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer** for new requirement

> But I have a problem with this, when a usuario does not have any likes or favoritos, it does not do the sum of total_interaction well, because the value of total_likes or total_favoritos is null. How can I do it?

Simply solve your `if null return 0` with `COALESCE()` operation, which it will [return the first non-null value in the list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

We will wrap the expression `likes_stats.total_likes` into

```
COALESCE(likes_stats.total_likes, 0)
```

meaning if the `likes_stats.total_likes` IS NULL, 0 will be returned

**Full query**

```
SELECT u.id_usuario, u.nombre_usuario, 
COALESCE(likes_stats.total_likes, 0) as total_likes, 
COALESCE(favoritos_stats.total_favoritos, 0) as total_favoritos,
COALESCE(likes_stats.total_likes, 0) + COALESCE(favoritos_stats.total_favoritos, 0) as total_interaction
FROM usuarios u
-- joining with the like count group by each user
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END as total_likes, id_usuario FROM likes
GROUP BY id_usuario) likes_stats ON u.id_usuario = likes_stats.id_usuario
-- joining with the favourite count group by each user
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as total_favoritos, id_usuario FROM favoritos
GROUP BY id_usuario) favoritos_stats ON u.id_usuario = favoritos_stats.id_usuario
ORDER BY likes_stats.total_likes DESC;
```

| id_usuario | nombre_usuario | total_likes | total_favoritos | total_interaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | manolo garcia | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | jose perez | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | antonio sanchez | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | manali tagret | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**Explanation**
You will need to join the user table with two additional statistic count table of the like per user, and the favorite per user.

**Like per usuario table** (with alias `likes_stats`) give you number of like of each usuario

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_likes, id_usuario FROM likes
GROUP BY id_usuario
```

| total_likes | id_usuario |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

**Favorito per usuario table** (with alias `favoritos_stats`) give you number of favorito of each usuario

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_favoritos, id_usuario FROM favoritos
GROUP BY id_usuario
```

| total_favoritos | id_usuario |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

Then we simply join the three tables: `usuario`, `likes_stats` and `favoritos_stats` by `id_usuario`.

You can order the row with your own preference by likes, or by favorito with `likes_stats.total_likes`, or `favoritos_stats.total_favoritos`

I also add the `total_interaction`, which is the sum of total like and favorito in case you want to sort by the total like and favorito together, just for convenience.

Here is the [SQL fiddle for the test schema you provided](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFmLYvhG5gdhvxTxT3DpYE/2)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

I have changed `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, because I am interested in showing all `usuarios`. But I have a problem with this, when a `usuario` does not have any `likes` or `favoritos`, it does not do the sum of `total_interaction` well, because the value of `total_likes` or `total_favoritos` is `null`.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @SousetPunset, please see my updated query with explanation and document, we will solve `if null return 0` concern with `COALESCE` operation.

Comment: Hi @SousetPunset, kindly let me know if you need further assist. If you find my answer helpful, please kindly accept and upvote it so that your question is no longer mark as "Not Answered". Thank you